# Replace style Segue issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am using a `Replace` style segue in `UISplitViewController`'s `DetailViewController`. My question is - when I replace the VC with the "replace segue", where goes the old one, does it get destroyed? If so, how can I re-instantiate the previous VC, the segue doesn't point both ways, does it?

Reason: I am trying to make TWO Detail Views that swap depending on the row clicked in the `UITable` in the Master View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to keep the replaced view controller?

Do you ARC? If you do, then keep a strong reference to both view controllers. That should prevent them from being "destroyed". 
If you don't then retain both view controller objects. That prevents them from being released until the release count is zero and then being deallocated.

When you re-display the now-not-destroyed view controller, make sure that you really reuse the existing object. Do not create a new one. (Most tutorials etc. should create a new one each time).

Comment: OK, thanks for that point, but where goes the old VC? How do I get it back? I call the replace simply by `[self.storyboard performSegue...]`. I set Style to `replace` in the IB. How do I call the replaced one?